# Visual Studio Code : Debugging unit tests works with net50 target framework but not with net48

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, .net-5, .net-4.8

I'm setting a test environment for a .net library using VS Code. I tried different configurations and after reading [this article](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/), I came up with this solution :

Project file :

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
        <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.13.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
      </ItemGroup>
    
    </Project>
```

Program.cs

```
    using System;
    using DebugTest.App;
    using DebugTest.Test;
    
    namespace DebugTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                UnitTests test = new UnitTests();
                test.Setup();
                test.TestAdd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Pseudo lib

```
    using System;
    
    namespace DebugTest.App
    {
        public static class Calculator
        {
            public static double Add(double x, double y)
            {
                return x + y;
            }
        }
    }
```

UnitTest.cs

```
    using System;
    using DebugTest.App;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    
    namespace DebugTest.Test
    {
       
        public class UnitTests
        {
            [SetUp]
            public void Setup()
            {
    
            }
    
            [Test]
            public void TestAdd()
            {
                double x = 2d;
                double y = 2d;
    
                Assert.AreEqual(9999d, Calculator.Add(x, y));
            }
            
        }
    }
```

With this configuration all works fine. I can :

- dotnet build
- dotnet test : starts the tests in terminal
- launch with appropriate configuration in launch.json : If I set breakpoints, I can debug tests through main method
- click on "Debug All Tests" or "Debug Test" lens in VSCode to debug tests.

Things got complicated when I tried to change the target framework from net5.0 to net48. I had to change my csproj this way :

New csproj

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
        <OutputType>exe</OutputType>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.13.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
      </ItemGroup>
    
    </Project>
```

What still works :

- dotnet build
- dotnet test

What doesn't work anymore :

- launch (I didn't forget to change the program path) : The program main is launched as I can see the exception for the failed test. In addition there are other warnings (The target process exited without raising CoreCLR...). If I set breakpoints in Program.cs or UnitTest.cs, they are not hit anymore
- click on "Debug All Tests" or "Debug Test" lens : Raises an error in VSCode : Failed to start debugger with a stacktrace mentionning OmniSharp.

I tried many things (cleaning bin and obj folders, etc) and read many forums threads with similar problems but none of them were related to net48.

So, my question is : How can I achieve test debugging in a net48 project in VSCode ?

Comment: You're trying to do is the reverse of upgrading from .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net 5. Upgrading isn't as simple as changing the target so why would the reverse?

Comment: Started with a .Net5 project as a proof of concept to have an overview of VSCode capabilities. The target libraries that I have to test are .NetFw48 (including nuget references and so on)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think a .Net 5 project was an appropriate proof of concept, there have been a lot of changes between the two - the whole of .Net Core for a start.

Comment: Not sure the problem is directly related to .Net 5 / .NetFw48. The same project works perfectly with both target frameworks in VS2019. I suspect there's something fishy with OmniSharp

Comment: OmniSharp says it has limited support for Desktop CLR debugging. See [wiki](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Desktop-.NET-Framework). It looks like there is a VS Code setting that has to be changed to enable it.